# Python Parsing subprocess Output

Tags: python, git

I am trying to save the output of

```
git remote show origin
```

with

```
  tempf = open('.tmp', 'w+')
  tempf2 = open('.tmp2', 'w+')
  subprocess.Popen(["git", "remote", "show", "origin"], stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf2)
  tempf.close()
  tempf2.close()
  output = open('.tmp', 'r')
  gitoutput = output.read()
```

and later parse the output with a regex.

However, the code above keeps returning `None` for `gitoutput`.

Is there something that I am missing? I am fairly confused as applying `.seek(0)` does not change the output and running `cat .tmp` shows the correct contents.

EDIT: `stderr` is also captured (`stderr=tempf2`) and thrown away as the git server produces unwanted output to the command line when running the script.

Comment: You can try `subprocess.check_call` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.wait()` with Popen

```
import subprocess
with open('.tmp', 'w+') as tempf,  open('.tmp2', 'w+') as tempf2:
    proc  = subprocess.Popen(["git", "remote", "show", "origin"], stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf2)
    proc.wait()
    tempf.seek(0)
    gitoutput = tempf.read()
print(gitoutput)
```

Or just use `check_call`:

```
with open('.tmp', 'w+') as tempf,  open('.tmp2', 'w+') as tempf2:
    proc  = subprocess.check_call(["git", "remote", "show", "origin"], stdout=tempf, stderr=tempf2)
    tempf.seek(0)
    gitoutput = tempf.read()
print(gitoutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(["git", "remote", "show", "origin"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
msg,err = child.communicate()
print msg
print err
```

here `communicate` will return a `tuple` containing the `output` and `error message` that is (stdoutdata,stderrdata)